# Button event not happening

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vite

I'm am learning learning typescript and am a beginner web dev. For some reason, "onclick", eventListner, and eventHandler, is not working in my project and I am lost as to why.

main.ts

```
import './style.css'
import 'animate.css'

document.querySelector<HTMLDivElement>('#app')!.innerHTML = `
<body>
  <div class="animate__animated animate__fadeIn animate__fast">

    <h1>TEEEDI</h1>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
      <h3>SERVICES</h3>
    </a>

    <button class="btn" onclick="alert("I have been clicked")>ABOUT</button>
    

    <div />

    <span>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/@teddi2">
        <h3><img src="/youtube100.png"/></h3>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/teddd.ii/">
        <h3><img src="/instagram100.png" /></h3>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.beatstars.com/prodteddi">
        <h3><img src="/beatstarscrop.png" /></h3>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@prod.teddix">
        <h3><img src="/tiktok100.png" /></h3>
      </a>
    </span>

    <script type="module" src="./about.ts></script>

  </div>
</body>
```

about.ts

```
// this script will update the about text
// when clicked to show either more details or less
/*export function aboutdesc(element: HTMLButtonElement) {
    let truth = true
    let test = () => {
        alert("This is a test")
    }

    element.addEventListener('click', () => test())
};*/


/*
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false)

function init(){
    function message () {
        alert('Hello!');
    }
}

var button = document.getElementById('button')
button?.addEventListener('click', init, true);
*/

let button: HTMLElement = document.querySelector(".btn")!;

button.onclick = () => {
    console.log("i have been clicked")
}
```

```
:root {
font-family: Inter, system-ui, Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
line-height: 1.5;
font-weight: 400;

color-scheme: light dark;
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
background-color: #242424;

font-synthesis: none;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
\-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
\-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
\-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

a {
font-weight: 500;
color: #646cff;
text-decoration: inherit;
}
a:hover {
color: #535bf2;
}

body {
margin: 0;
display: flex;
place-items: center;
min-width: 320px;
min-height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
font-size: 3.2em;
line-height: 1.1;
}

\#app {
max-width: 1280px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 2rem;
text-align: center;
}

.logo {
height: 6em;
padding: 1.5em;
will-change: filter;
transition: filter 300ms;
}
.logo:hover {
filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2em #646cffaa);
}
.logo.vanilla:hover {
filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2em #3178c6aa);
}

.card {
padding: 2em;
}

.read-the-docs {
color: #888;
}

button {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 2rem;
color: white;
transition: 0.3s;
filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.1rem white);
outline: 0px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border: none;
transition: 0.3s
}

button:hover {
filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.5rem white);
cursor: pointer;
}

body {
background:  linear-gradient(
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
),url("/background.gif");
background-repeat: none;
background-size: cover;
}

div h1 {
color: white;
font-family: "STRRETCH SANS FREE";
animation-name: glowing;
animation-duration: 5s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
font-size: 5rem;
}

div h3 {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 2rem;
color: white;
filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.1rem white);
transition: 0.3s
}

div h3:hover {
filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.5rem white);
}

@keyframes glowing {
0% {filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.75rem white);}
50% {filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.5rem white);}
100% {filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.75rem white);}

}

a:link {
text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
}

img {
filter: invert(1);
}

span h3{
display: inline-block
}
```

I have tried using eventListener to log "I am clicked" into the console, only to see nothing in the console. I have tried btn.onclick for my code to only throw up errors.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put the closing quote after the sourcing of /about.ts and as for the onclick maybe try making a function and sourcing that to alert it

also don't use query selector but rather use document.getElementById() for getting ID elements

here is the edited code

```
import './style.css'
import 'animate.css'

document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = `
<body>
  <div class="animate__animated animate__fadeIn animate__fast">

    <h1>TEEEDI</h1>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
      <h3>SERVICES</h3>
    </a>

    <button class="btn" onclick="myFunc()">ABOUT</button>
    

    <div />

    <span>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/@teddi2">
        <h3><img src="/youtube100.png"/></h3>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/teddd.ii/">
        <h3><img src="/instagram100.png" /></h3>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.beatstars.com/prodteddi">
        <h3><img src="/beatstarscrop.png" /></h3>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@prod.teddix">
        <h3><img src="/tiktok100.png" /></h3>
      </a>
    </span>

    <script type="module" src="./about.ts"></script>

  </div>
<script>
  function myFunc() {
    alert("I have been clicked")
  }
</script>
`
```

also addressing the.part which says i am clicked does not appear that is because button.onclick does not check constantly

you can try

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
   console.log('i have been clicked')
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I think I may have run into an issue outside of the code. The code works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b01jkep4/) but returns [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pL2cwzLs_QkYXjWE6dCeIRkZqsqsnXAb/view?usp=sharing) when I try and run it in my browser. If it helps, I'm using firefox and vite. Any help is appreciated.